# Javascript/Ecmascript get parent's this-variable

Tags: javascript, inheritance, parameters, ecmascript-6

I have a question about javascript variable inheritance.

I am trying to create a small library, but I wasn't able to push-through some variable into the sublibrary.

At first I've created the root function:

```
function myLibrary(param) {
  this.param = param
}
```

and later on I wanted to expand on it but in modules, so I created the first one and wanted to get `param` from the `myLibrary` root but it didn't work:

```
myLibrary.prototype.myModule = {
  test: function() {
    console.log(this.param) // doesn't work - logs "unknown"
  }
}
```

Is there any way to make it work? Like in the way that I call

```
myLibrary("foo").myModule.test();
```

and the `foo` gets logged?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: was there any question helpful for you? If yes - mark the related one as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When assigning a field on `this` in an anonymous function you're assigning to the window object.  To use prototypical inheritance use your function as a constructor with the `new` keyword, or manually assign the `__proto__` field.

Furthermore, you're going to have trouble getting `test` to recognize the correct context due to it being on a separate object.

So, to not change your call. I'd change the way your library "builds itself" and use encapsulation instead of a class.

```js
function myLibrary(param) {
  var mylib = {};
  
  mylib.myModule = {
    test: function(){
      console.log(param);
    }
  };
  
  return mylib;
}

myLibrary("foo").myModule.test(); // logs foo
```

This is a pretty common pattern and is used regularly.

However if you're set on using inheritance, lookup classes in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

You have 3 ways:
1 - create method on prototype:

```
myLibrary.prototype.test = function() {
  console.log(this.param) 
}

new myLibrary("foo").test();
```

2 - create prototype from scratch:

```
myLibrary.prototype = {
  test: function() {
    console.log(this.param) 
  }
}

new myLibrary("foo").test();
```

3 - or go the way Benjamin wrote in the answer - implementing [module](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript) pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can make changes like below

```
myLibrary.prototype.myModule = (function(){
    var _private = this.param;
    return {
  test: function() {
    console.log(_private) // will work
  }};
})();
```

Call the test function as below:

```
new myLibrary("foo").myModule.test();
```

Answer (score 0):

we can create a closure, refer this:

```
    function MyLibrary(param) {// Please make sure that constructor 
                                 // name starts with capital.
      this.param = param;
    }

    MyLibrary.prototype.myModule = function(){
    var newParam = this.param; //free variable
      test = function() {  //closed function
        console.log(newParam) 
      }
      return test;
    }
    var myLibrary = new MyLibrary("foo"); //creating new library object
    var test = myLibrary.myModule();     //taking method returned by 
                                        //myModule
    test();//invoking it.
```